# javascript submit button onsubmit show PHP Posted values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var res = confirm('Do you really want to submit the form? <?php echo $_POST["contact"]; ?>');
    if(!res) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ticket_update").submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

when the `submit` button is clicked it displays a confirmation box. i want to make the PHP Posted values display on the confirmation box - i have tried it above but its not showing anything.

any ideas how i can do this?

Comment: Yes because php does work way before javascript gets executed and php values have not sent to the server in your code, you are accessing those value before submitting the form

Comment: why u dont try to get these values from Javascript not PHP , i mean u can get the value of the element using JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the php post variables because the form hasn't been submited yet, do like this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var res = confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?' + $("input[name='contact']").val());
    if(!res) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ticket_update").submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the execution timeline, PHP is first, back there on server, and JavaScript acts later, on the browser. It means you can prepare JavaScript with php, but not the other way around.

One way to get your result would be to create file like "javascript_variables.php", that would be included into your html using `<script>` tag, with content like:

```
var contact = "<?php echo $_POST["contact"]; ?>";
```

Then you can just use `contact` variable in other js files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `.serialize()` of jquery:

```
    var res = confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?' + 
                       $("#ticket_update").serialize());
```

Try using this and see if this solves the issue.

[**Fiddle Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8xX5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $_POST = <?php echo $_POST["contact"]; ?>    
    var res = confirm('Do you really want to submit the form? $_POST["contact"]');
    if(!res) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ticket_update").submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#submit').click(function() {
                    var res = confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?'+ $('#contact').val());
                    if(!res) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("ticket_update").submit();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="addticketupdate.php">
            <input type="text" id="contact" value="Hello"/>
            <button id="submit" type="submit">shfkj</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can get input value using `jquery` as `$('#contact').val())`